# Chrome Extension: script injected into iframe can't access its content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've got a Chrome Extension that loads an `iframe` with some buttons whose functionality I want to control with a script, which I inject into that `iframe`. However, I can't access elements using `document.getElementById()`, and printing the `document.body` to the console says "null". Here's a minimal example:

Main content script:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = browser.extension.getURL("login_form.html");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

iframe HTML  (`login_form.html`):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='login_form.js' type="text/javascript"> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="login-button">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS inserted into iframe (`login_form.js`)

```js
console.log(document);
console.log(document.body);
console.log(document.getElementById("login-button"));
```

Here, the first call to `console.log`, as expected, prints the `iframe`'s DOM. However, the following two calls return "null".

---

Related problems I've seen:
I know there are issues with cross-domain access and `iframe`s, but this seems to be a different case as both the `iframe` and the JS are under the same domain (my extension). I've also seen other questions where the solution was to execute main content script with `all_frames: true`, but I think this case is different to my case because it's not the content script itself that's supposed to go into the `iframe`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your script running after the DOM is loaded?  If it just has those 3 lines of code then I'd *expect* the body and any elements to not be found.  Move the script tag to the bottom of the body and try it again.

Comment: Oops, that's embarrassing! This did the trick indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Lol - no worries.  Glad to help :)